# Compiled in Release mode a naming conflict occurs but not in Debug mode. Why?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, compilation, namespaces

In Debug mode my program works as expected but a naming conflict appears only in Release mode:

***Cannot assign object of type ProjectService.Project to an object of type ProjectAdminService2.Project.***

I'm referencing two web services (ProjectService and ProjectAdminService2) in a repository (class library project). The bug appeared after I added a reference to ProjectService.

When I delete the ProjectService reference everything works fine but I need that reference. Even when I fully qualify the names for all references to Project (using only ProjectAdminService2.Project) this strange bug remains. The problem appears to be within the web service I'm referencing. These services are part of an API and the internal code is out of my control.

**What might cause such a problem to appear only when compiled in Release mode?** It was rather disconcerting because I only discovered the problem after it was published to a production environment.

Comment: Have you tried deleting everything in the bin\Release folder and recompiling?

Comment: I just tried that and the problem remains.

Comment: I imagine you could construct this situation by having enough of your code wrapped in `#if Debug` blocks, but you'd need to be more or less intentionally constructing this evil situation.